# Possible to Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in an SFMC Landingpage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ajax, landing-page

we want load some content from an SFMC Landingpage using AJAX on our Webpage.

But its not working in every Browser because the CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing on the SFMC Landingpage.

Is it possible to activate it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out a Solution.

Its possible to Set the Header using Server-Side JavaScript within the Landingpage.

Here is my Header and its working fine now.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
</script>
```