# CORS Issue on Personalization Builder output

Tags: marketing-cloud, cors, einstein-recommendations

Our current implementation method uses SFMC's client-side code snippet that returns and places it's HTML in our module and outputs the following on the page:

```
<script src="https://[MID].recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/[MID]/category/recommend.js?category=Living%20and%20Wellness&amp;item=182520" async=""></script>
```

We'd like to get the JSON object directly from our client-side script but the request is blocked by the following CORS (cross-origin resource policy) error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[MID].recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/[MID]/category/recommend.json?category=Living%20and%20Wellness&item=182520' from origin [Site URL] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Has anyone else ever seen this? Any suggestions for addressing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow / setup CORS on the server `https://7201305.recs.igodigital.com` to allow requests from `https://wordpress-healthbeat-dev.azurewebsites.net`. That is why you are receiving an error

Comment: Thank you. How do we do that? We don't have access to the server for igodigital.com as that is managed by Salesforce.

Comment: I am not a SFMC expert, but there should be some options to whitelist certain origins.

Comment: This may have the solution you are looking for https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137172/possible-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-an-sfmc-landingpage

Comment: Unfortunately not, as that solution is for accessing content from a page where we would have at least some control over it's settings. We are trying to access a dynamically generated JSON file. In our settings, we've whitelisted our domain and no change. We've even tried following this, but it's not available for Marketing Cloud: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! **Lukas Lunow** [said here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286187/how-to-get-the-json-response-using-einstein-in-web-recommendations/286196#286196) that we can access the object by using the **callback** parameter like so:

```
<script src="https://[MID].recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/[MID]/category/recommend.js?category=Living%20and%20Wellness&item=182520&callback=foobar"></script>
```

And then in my script, I defined the callback like so:

```
function foobar(obj) {
    //Do something with obj!
}
```

This is great for complying with the CORS policy!