# How to get the JSON response using Einstein in Web Recommendations?

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, einstein, cors, einstein-recommendations

According to [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_web_recommendation.htm&type=5), web recommendations can be delivered via JSON response or HTML/JS. It mentions that the JSON response is the best method. However, there is no documentation for getting it. The only documentation they have covers the [HTML/JS method](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_get_code_details.htm&type=5).

Now I am able to see the JSON object when I view the URL in the browser (details removed for security purposes): https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/{MID}>/category/recommend.json?category={CATEGORY}&item={CONTENT_ID}

but using it in JavaScript like this yields this CORS policy error, preventing me from getting anything:

**JavaScript snippet**

```
<script>
    $.getJSON("https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/{MID}>/category/recommend.json?category={CATEGORY}&item={CONTENT_ID}",
        function(response, status, xhr) {
            //Do something with response
        }).error(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            //Do something with error, I always end up here with the CORS error
        });
</script>
```

**Error**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/{MID}>/category/recommend.json?category={CATEGORY}&item={CONTENT_ID}'
>   from origin {SITE_URL} has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Obviously I cannot adjust the server settings for igodigital to modify the JSON file's headers to allow my site access since that's managed by Salesforce.

I attempted to whitelist my site's domain using [these instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_code_cors.htm&type=5), but I can't get past step 1 because it's only available in *Salesforce Classic* and *Lightning Experience*, not *Marketing Cloud*.

I did find a "whitelist" section in my settings where I added my domain and checked the box to activate them, but it didn't do anything.

If this isn't the way to get the JSON response, what is??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make use of callback parameter in the call to *recommend.json* - you can easily append it if you have existing parameters in your querystring:

```
https://{MID}.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/{MID}>/category/recommend.json?category={CATEGORY}&item={CONTENT_ID}&callback=foobar
```

This will wrap the response in a function call with the name passed in the URL:

E.g.:

```
foobar([{"name":"igdrec_1","title":"Most Viewed Items","priority":1,"items":[{},{},{}]}]);
```

vs (without callback param):

```
[{"name":"igdrec_1","title":"Most Viewed Items","priority":1,"items":[{},{},{}]}]
```

There is a number of good resources out there, describing how to use JSONP and callback to overcome CORS challenges, a.o.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521856/cross-domain-javascript-calls-using-jsonp-or-cors
or:
https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/using-jsonp-for-cross-domain-requests/

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Unless you wear a cape. Then they do. THANK YOU!!

Comment: You are most welcome, @Tessa. I’m glad I could help

Comment: hey @LukasLunow - thats a good one! added it to the [cookbook](https://joernberkefeld.github.io/SFMC-Cookbook/einstein/recommendation/#embed-via-json) ;-) however, is there no way to tweak the CORS headers? the current configuration seems to be more of an accident than on purpose given that somebody actively configured **same-origin** for this endpoint - which is clearly meant for cross origin use